# Is it possible to suffocate an enemy crew with only Ion Blast II?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

Given an enemy ship with 1/1/1 shields/O2/medbay, is it possible to suffocate the crew using only one Ion Blast Mark II? Bonus points for video proof :)

I ran out of drones on my Torus and have no other weapons :(

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Holy crap, it is:

[image: Suffocation with Ion Blast II]

I was fighting the [dread pirate Tuco](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Pirate_Tuco) and after he ran out of bombs (and thus could no longer damage my ship with only a single puny laser) I set my Ion Blast II on his O2 and went to watch some football.

When I came back he was still alive, but all my crew members had been fully leveled at their respective stations, and after I switched to his medbay after a few rounds of knocking out his shields and medbay his crew suffocated!

And after all that, of course I did not get any drone parts out of it...